# Problems with moving Apache server home directory

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu-12.04, ftp

I recently moved my server's web root to a new hard drive.
After transferring the files, I edited the site file under /etc/apache2/sites-enabled to point to the new directory location.
I made sure to preserve the file permissions while copying, and I can load its web pages as I could before, but now I am unable to log in via FTP (error 530) on another computer.
Is there anything that you would suggest that might fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check the home directory for the user you are logging in with via FTP. Is it the old root of the web server? If so change it to the new path.

Check home directory of user:

```
grep username /etc/passwd
```

Change home directory of user:

```
sudo usermod -d /path/to/new/home
```